# WebAuthn request timeout is not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, browser, navigator, webauthn

I am passing this `public key`

```
const publicKey = {
    "challenge": "testchanllengevalue",
    "rp": { "name": "test.com" },
    "user": {
      "id": "12345-543212-12345-54321",
      "name": "NAME",
      "displayName": "NAME"
    },
    "attestation": "direct",
    "timeout": 20000,
    "authenticatorSelection": {
      "authenticatorAttachment": "platform",
      "requireResidentKey": false,
      "userVerification": "required"
    },
    "pubKeyCredParams": [
      { "type": "public-key", "alg": -7 },
      { "type": "public-key", "alg": -257 }
    ]
}
```

To  `navigator.credentials.create({ 'publicKey': publicKey })`

And the timeout works fine on a desktop and stops the request but on mobile devices the finger print or face id request never times out.

Am I missing something here or is their another way to do this for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

Only speaking for Android, but for Android < 14, WebAuthn operations are handled by Play Services, and Play Services doesn't support timing out of requets. Thus the timeout will not have an effect there.

(As an aside, a timeout of `20000` means 20 seconds, which is hopefully only for illustrative purposes. The value should reflect the amount of time which the RP is willing to trust other authenticator factors (in 2nd-factor authentications) or can establish the validity of a challenge (in all modes) and should be larger than 20 seconds. The spec [currently recommends](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-createCredential) a minimum of five minutes.)